# Derivative of Multivariate Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Assume $M_\theta = \sum \theta_iM_i, \phi(M_\theta) \text{ is a differentiable function }\mathbb{R}^{n\times m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \theta = [\theta_1 \dots \theta_N]$. I want to find $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial \theta_i}$

Using the chain rule: $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial \theta_i}=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial M_\theta}\frac{\partial M_\theta}{\partial \theta_i} = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial M_\theta} M_i$. However, the answer should be the dot product $<M_i,\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial M_\theta}>$. I am not sure how to obtain the correct answer?

Comment: This is just way too sloppy for me. $\phi$ is a function of $n\times m$ matrices. Writing $\partial \phi/\partial\theta_i$ makes absolutely no sense. There are $N$ variables $\theta_1,\dots,\theta_N$? What shape are the matrices $M_i$ so that $M_\theta$ comes out $n\times m$?

Comment: @TedShifrin $M_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$. You can look at the input of $\phi$ as a function that takes a matrix which its each element is a weighted combination of $\theta_i$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $\phi$ is a function of $n\times m$ matrices. There's no such thing as $\partial \phi/\partial M_\theta$; this is a "total" derivative $D\phi$. OK, so let's let $g(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_N) = \sum \theta_i M_i = M_\theta$. Then we're interested in $f(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_N) = \phi(g(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_N))$. The chain rule tells us that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta_i} = D\phi(g(\theta))\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial\theta_i}\right) = D\phi(g(\theta))(M_i).$$
Note that $\phi$, as a map $M^{n\times m}\to\Bbb R$ has a derivative, which is a linear map also mapping $M^{n\times m}\to\Bbb R$. So you apply that linear map to the $m\times n$ matrix $M_i$ and you get the answer. I would never write the notation that you're using. We could write $\phi'(M_\theta)$ instead of $D\phi(M_\theta)$.

You can think of evaluating this linear map on $M_i$ as a directional derivative in the direction of $M_i$, which is given, as you learned in multivariable calculus, the inner product of the gradient of $\phi$ with the direction vector $M_i$.

If you want to give me a specific example of a function $\phi$ you're working with, I can try to illustrate further.

Comment: I in a paper, they evaluated the derivative with respect to $\theta_i$ of the function $\phi(M_\theta)$ as $<M_i, \triangledown \phi(M_\theta) >$. https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00756802/document Page 5 the second column. Under the coordinate descent algorithm section. I do not understand how they come up with this. I think your solution is consistent with mine not theirs.

Comment: What they're saying is consistent with my final comment. In (finite-dimensional) calculus, the directional derivative $D_v f(a)$ is given by $\langle \nabla f(a),v\rangle$.

Comment: $D\phi(g(\theta))(M_i)$ will not give a real number. It will always give a vector or a matrix. Not sure how this consistent with inner product.

Comment: No, no. $\phi$ is real-valued, so its derivative sends a tangent vector (matrix here) to a real number.

Comment: Well, (()) $\in R^{n\times m}$ and  $\in R^{m \times n}$. How can this result in a scalar? Sorry, but I still don't get it.

Comment: Huh? You typed that $\phi$ is real-valued.

Comment: Sorry, I mean even in the case of (()) ∈ and  ∈$^{×}$. It still a matrix though. You multiply a scalar with a matrix.

Comment: No. You are not understanding ... this is not matrix multiplication. This is evaluating a linear map with domain $V$ and range $\Bbb R$ on an element of $V$.